Local cross-sections of a Hopf bundle
The group $\mathrm{Spin}(9)$ is the total space of the fibre bundle over the sphere $S^{15}$ with fibres that are copies of $\mathrm{Spin(7)}$. It has no continuous global cross-sections. Is it possible to construct a local one with open dense domain?

Let can be done for any fiber bundle. In your case, $S^{15}$ minus a point is contractible and thus the fiber bundle restricted to it is trivial.

Thanks, Arctic Char! I know that such a cross-section exists! My question is about construction!
